# I am facing an issue with image augmentation using albumentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo, data-augmentation, albumentations

I am new to deep learning and computer vision. I recently did a tutorial on implementation of yolov1. Now I am trying it with a different dataset.

Here is my code-

```
def get_bboxes(filename):
  name = filename[:-4]
  indices = meta_df[meta_df['new_img_id'] == float(name)]
  bounding_boxes = []
  for index, row in indices.iterrows():
    x = float(row['x'])
    y = float(row['y'])
    w = float(row['width'])
    h = float(row['height'])
    im_w = float(row['img_width'])
    im_h = float(row['img_height'])
    class_id = int(row['cat_id'])
    bounding_box = [(x+w/2)/(im_w), (y+h/2)/(im_h), w/im_w, h/im_h, class_id]
    bounding_boxes.append(bounding_box)
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(bounding_boxes, dtype=tf.float32)

def generate_output(bounding_boxes):
  output_label = np.zeros([int(SPLIT_SIZE), int(SPLIT_SIZE), int(N_CLASSES+5)])
  for b in range(len(bounding_boxes)):
    grid_x = bounding_boxes[...,b,0]*SPLIT_SIZE
    grid_y = bounding_boxes[...,b,1]*SPLIT_SIZE

    i = int(grid_x)
    j = int(grid_y)

    output_label[i, j, 0:5] = [1., grid_x%1, grid_y%1, bounding_boxes[...,b,2], bounding_boxes[...,b,3]]
    output_label[i, j, 5+int(bounding_boxes[...,b,4])] = 1.

  return tf.convert_to_tensor(output_label, tf.float32)

def get_imboxes(im_path, map):
  img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file('./new_dataset/'+im_path))
  img = tf.cast(tf.image.resize(img, [H,W]), dtype=tf.float32)

  bboxes = tf.numpy_function(func=get_bboxes, inp=[im_path], Tout=tf.float32)

  return img, bboxes

train_ds2 = train_ds1.map(get_imboxes)
val_ds2 = val_ds1.map(get_imboxes)

transforms = A.Compose([
    A.Resize(H,W),
    A.RandomCrop(
        width = np.random.randint(int(0.9*W), W),
        height = np.random.randint(int(0.9*H), H), p=0.5),
    A.RandomScale(scale_limit=0.1, interpolation=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4, p=0.5),
    A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
    A.Resize(H,W)
], bbox_params =A.BboxParams(format='yolo'))

def aug_albument(image, bboxes):
  augmented = transforms(image = image, bboxes = bboxes)
  return [tf.convert_to_tensor(augmented['image'], dtype=tf.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(augmented['bboxes'], dtype=tf.float32)]

def process_data(image, bboxes):
  aug = tf.numpy_function(func=aug_albument, inp=[image, bboxes], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32))
  return aug[0], aug[1]

train_ds3 = train_ds2.map(process_data)
```

I am getting a error in the albumentation.

when I write these lines-

```
for i, j in train_ds3:
  print(j)
```

I get this error-`InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ValueError: Expected y_min for bbox (0.203125, -0.002777785062789917, 0.8187500238418579, 0.8694444596767426, 5.0) to be in the range [0.0, 1.0], got -0.002777785062789917.`
I checked all the labels of train_ds2. But I could not find any negative value. What am I missing here?

I tried commenting the all the albumentation operations on image but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

In your get_bboxes() function, you will get the values ​​as follows:
`x = float(row['x']) y = float(row['y']) w = float(row['width']) h = float(row['height'])`. When you retrieve data in the form x, y, w, h it implies that it is already the x_center and the y_center. So when you do `(x+w/2)/(im_w)` or even `(y+h/2)/(im_h)`, it calculates the x_max and y_max instead. The format will be incorrect and until then you will have no problem in `train_ds2`. The problem will occur when you use albumentations with `format='yolo'`. It will receive an incorrect format and that is probably the reason for the negative values.

The solution I think will be to modify your `get_bboxes()` function as follows:

```
bounding_box = [x/im_w, y/im_h, w/im_w, h/im_h, class_id]
```

I don't know the format of your data so if I'm wrong, please provide more details on the format used.

Comment: I tried to find the format by plotting them. x and y are the coordinates of upper left corner. With that I have bounding box width and height, image width, image height.

I tried adding some small values to the y_min before albumentation, but after that I get an error where either x_max or y_max is greater than 1

 I think the problem is in dataset itself. May be not properly annotated.

Comment: Maybe. Try with an other dataset.